# Is hierachical parallelism possible with MPI libraries?

Tags: mpi

I'm writing a computational code with MPI. I have a few parts of the software each compute different part of the problem. Each part is written with MPI thus could be run as an independent module. Now I want to combine these parts to be run together within one program, and all parts of the code run in parallel while each part itself is also running in parallel.

e.g. Total number of nodes = 10, part1 run with 6 nodes and part 2 run with 4 nodes and both running together.

Is there ways that I can mpirun with 10 nodes and mpi_init each part with desired number of node without rewritten the overall program to allocate process for each part of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not straightforward.

One option is to use an external program that with `MPI_Comm_spawn()` (twice) your sub-programs. The drawback is this requires one slot.

An other option needs some rewriting, since all the tasks will end up in the same `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, it is up to them to `MPI_Comm_split()` based on who they are, and use the resulting communicator instead of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

Comment: I think MPI_Comm_split() is the best way I should go with minimum code change. Thank you a lot Gilles.

Comment: you can use the `MPI_APP_NUM` attribute of `MPI_COMM_WORLD` to get the color you will use for the split https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node113.htm